# How do we factor $2\sin(\theta)-1=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The equation is
$$2\sin(\theta)-1=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$$

We want to factor it so that we can use the zero factor property.

Comment: To do that, you first have to group all the terms on one side of the equation.  That said, this particular equation would be easier to solve by completing the square or applying the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is equivalent to $$2\sin^2(\theta)+2\sin(\theta)-2=0$$

or
$$\sin^2(\theta)+\sin(\theta)-1=0$$

If you put $ x=\sin(\theta)$, with $ -1\le x\le 1$,

it becomes

$$\color{red}{1}x^2+x-1=0$$

$$\Delta=1+4=5$$
thus

$x_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 0.6$

and

$x_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx -1.6$

So, the equation will be

$$\color{red}{1}(\sin(\theta)-x_1)(\sin(\theta)-x_2)=0$$

Comment: Hey, I don't understand where you got 4 and 5 from. Starting from where you put delta, it gets confusing. Also, why did you put sin theta into the domain of the inverse of sin?

Comment: @IlIllIlllllllIllIlIllIIlIII For $ax^2+bx+c=0$, $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32024/blindly-answering-easy-questions-without-considering-whether-the-question-satisf) is for you.

Comment: @Doubtnut Yes, you are certainly right. From now on, i will take this into account. But could explain to me why do i loose points everyday With No reason (user removed, downvote,...)

Comment: Well, I don't about everyday but I downvoted this question. As quoted in the FAQ thread, "do feel free to downvote overly complete answers to known homework (as in, you know that this instance of the question is homework) if you think the asker has not done enough to 'deserve' it". I'll not upvote unless it is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward: let $s=\sin(\theta)$.  Then we have $2s-1=1-s^2\iff 4s^2+4s-4=0$.  Now
$$\begin{align}
4s^2+4s-4&=4s^2+4s+1-1-4\\\
&=(2s+1)^2-5\\
&=(2s+1+\sqrt5)(2s+1-\sqrt5).
\end{align}
$$